# Website is not centred & issues with spacing of line seperator

Tags: html, css

I am helping some friends to create their website. But I am facing 2 issues, that I am desperately trying to fix.

1. The site is supposed to be a non-scrollable one-pager. But for some reason, it is not centred and you need to scroll. I am desperately trying to figure out why.
2. Why is there so much space between the first line of text and the first dotted line? Also I can not change the size of the dots. No matter what size I set.

Here's the website: https://www.ideenschmelze.de/

PS: The HTML is embedded as an Elementor element. I first thought that's causing the scrolling issues. But if I don't make it via Elementor, the logo is also displaced horizontally.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
 body {
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
 
  }
  .orange-theme {
    background-color: #F08831;
  }
  .blue-theme {
    background-color: #4FC1EC;
  }
  .default-theme {
    background-color: white;
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 900px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  #change-background-blue
  {
      margin-bottom: 20vh;
      margin-right: 20px; 
  }
 #change-background-orange
  {
      margin-bottom: 20vh;
      margin-right: 20px; 
  }
  }
  
.button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
  
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:40vh;width:100vw;" class="orange" id="change-background-orange">
<div id="wir" style="opacity:0">
<p><span style="font-size:2.5em">Wir</span><br>
... mögen Herausforderungen, Effizienz, Ästethik und unkreative Aufzählungen. 
<hr style="border-style: dashed; size: 5px;">
... sind ein eingespieltes, interdisziplinäres Team, das mittels spitzfindiger Kreativarbeit und wertschätzender Kommunikation einfach das tut was es liebt. 
<hr style="border-style: dashed; size: 5px;">
... geben Innovationsfreiheit den Vorzug vor monetärem Gewinn, deshalb entscheidet ihr selbst, wie viel euch unser Beitrag wert ist.

</p>
</div>
</div>
<img id="logo" src="http://www.ideenschmelze.de/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/cropped-drip_drop_final_groß-1024x141.png" class="wp-image-124" id="logo" style="float:centre; width:100vw; height:20vh"/>
<div style="height:40vh;width:100vw;" class="blue" id="change-background-blue">
<div id="ihr" style="opacity:0">
<p><span style="font-size:2.5em">Ihr</span><br>
... benötigt ein Logo, Werbetexte,einen Slogan, Printmedien, CI oder eine komplette Marketingstrategie?<br>
... seid auf der Suche nach einem Ansprechpartner, der trotz beschränktem Werbebudget eueren Wunsch erfolgreich umsetzt? <br>
Dann schüttet uns euer Herz aus, schildert uns eure Probleme oder schwärmt von euren Visionen!
</p>
<a href="mailto:hallo@ideenschmelze.de">Send uns eine Email</a>
</div>
</div>

<script>
var wir = document.getElementById("wir");
var ihr = document.getElementById("ihr");

 document.getElementById("change-background-orange").addEventListener("mouseover", function()   {
 document.body.classList.remove("blue-theme");  
 document.body.classList.remove("default-theme");
 document.body.classList.add("orange-theme");
 wir.style.opacity = 1;
 ihr.style.opacity = 0;
});

 document.getElementById("change-background-blue").addEventListener("mouseover", function()   {
 //document.getElementById//("logo").src="newSource//.png";     
 document.body.classList.remove("orange-theme"); 
 document.body.classList.remove("default-theme");
 document.body.classList.add("blue-theme");
 wir.style.opacity = 0;
 ihr.style.opacity = 1;
});

 document.getElementById("logo").addEventListener("mouseover", function()   {
 document.body.classList.remove("blue-theme");  
 document.body.classList.remove("orange-theme"); 
 document.body.classList.add("default-theme");
 wir.style.opacity = 0;
 ihr.style.opacity = 0;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance
Tobias

Comment: Read My solution It will work

Comment: is that you want something more please ask that in comment

Answer (score 0):

Some of the div has too much height like 40vh it means viewport height so I turn it down a bit to 20vh. You should think of the browser's Bookmarks and menus also.

For your second item, the p element default has some margin so you have to override it.
Here you go:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
 body {
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
 
  }
  .orange-theme {
    background-color: #F08831;
  }
  .blue-theme {
    background-color: #4FC1EC;
  }
  .default-theme {
    background-color: white;
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 900px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  #change-background-blue
  {
      margin-bottom: 20vh;
      margin-right: 20px; 
  }
 #change-background-orange
  {
      margin-bottom: 20vh;
      margin-right: 20px; 
  }
  }
  
.button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

  
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:40vh;width:100vw;" class="orange" id="change-background-orange">
<div id="wir" style="opacity:0">
<p><span style="font-size:2.5em">Wir</span><br>
... mögen Herausforderungen, Effizienz, Ästethik und unkreative Aufzählungen. 
<hr style="border-style: dashed; size: 5px;">
... sind ein eingespieltes, interdisziplinäres Team, das mittels spitzfindiger Kreativarbeit und wertschätzender Kommunikation einfach das tut was es liebt. 
<hr style="border-style: dashed; size: 5px;">
... geben Innovationsfreiheit den Vorzug vor monetärem Gewinn, deshalb entscheidet ihr selbst, wie viel euch unser Beitrag wert ist.

</p>
</div>
</div>
<img id="logo" src="http://www.ideenschmelze.de/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/cropped-drip_drop_final_groß-1024x141.png" class="wp-image-124" id="logo" style="float:centre; width:100vw; height:20vh"/>
<div style="height:20vh;width:100vw;" class="blue" id="change-background-blue">
<div id="ihr" style="opacity:0">
<p><span style="font-size:2.5em">Ihr</span><br>
... benötigt ein Logo, Werbetexte,einen Slogan, Printmedien, CI oder eine komplette Marketingstrategie?<br>
... seid auf der Suche nach einem Ansprechpartner, der trotz beschränktem Werbebudget eueren Wunsch erfolgreich umsetzt? <br>
Dann schüttet uns euer Herz aus, schildert uns eure Probleme oder schwärmt von euren Visionen!
</p>
<a href="mailto:hallo@ideenschmelze.de">Send uns eine Email</a>
</div>
</div>

<script>
var wir = document.getElementById("wir");
var ihr = document.getElementById("ihr");

 document.getElementById("change-background-orange").addEventListener("mouseover", function()   {
 document.body.classList.remove("blue-theme");  
 document.body.classList.remove("default-theme");
 document.body.classList.add("orange-theme");
 wir.style.opacity = 1;
 ihr.style.opacity = 0;
});

 document.getElementById("change-background-blue").addEventListener("mouseover", function()   {
 //document.getElementById//("logo").src="newSource//.png";     
 document.body.classList.remove("orange-theme"); 
 document.body.classList.remove("default-theme");
 document.body.classList.add("blue-theme");
 wir.style.opacity = 0;
 ihr.style.opacity = 1;
});

 document.getElementById("logo").addEventListener("mouseover", function()   {
 document.body.classList.remove("blue-theme");  
 document.body.classList.remove("orange-theme"); 
 document.body.classList.add("default-theme");
 wir.style.opacity = 0;
 ihr.style.opacity = 0;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked fined. 
How about the size of the dotted line? I try to make it bolder, but it doesn't change, when I adjust the size of the <hr> element.

Answer (score -1):

You need a minor change here. Just add these lines of code. I know you didn't write this here. But try to implement them. As I find them on your website and from dev tools I tried to change them and they worked as you guys want. Just see the image. There is no scrollbar on the screen.
**Problem:1-Solution**
[image]

```
.col{
height:20px;
}
```

you have to make these changes here.

[image]

In you server location is this:

```
https://www.ideenschmelze.de/wp-content/themes/neve/style.min.css?ver=2.7.6
```

**Problem:2 - Solution** you have to remove the margin-bottom from the p tag which you will find at the same file in which you have to change `.col` property.
[image]
Just remove the margin-top property which was initially present here, I removed that from here.
And finally, your website is like as you want:

[image]